# Resumable file uploads for Cordova/Phonegap, android platform

Tags: cordova, file-upload, resume-upload

can any one help out with snippets or an existing plugin for resumable, fault tolerant uploads for phonegap / cordova (Android). I've been trying to look in Cordova file and file transfer plugin native code but my Java sucks. I will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I could not get a native android solution using Java. I got something that uses XHR. This link helped
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-200?focusedCommentId=13987755&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13987755

Coupled with flow.js, I got fault tolerant resumable uploads on phonegap/cordova